# How to select non english characters?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some variables which include non english chars like İ,ş,ö. I can insert them to mysql db but they convert to some special characters. For example:

> Faz 1/İzmir/İzmir/Konak 1. Merkezinden  Faz1/İzmir/İzmir/Konak 2.
>   Merkezine  bilgisi ile yeni Erişim kaydı yapıldı

to

> Faz 1/Ä°zmir/Ä°zmir/Konak 1. Merkezinden  Faz1/Ä°zmir/Ä°zmir/Konak 2.
>   Merkezine  bilgisi ile yeni Erişim kaydı yapıldı.

it is  sql code:

```
$sql = "SELECT username, islem, tarih  FROM loglar where kullanici_id= ".$gelen_id." order by tarih desc" ;  
$_SESSION["VT"]->doQuery($sql);
```

Then i cannot get them. it returns null althogh it is in db. and I cannot display in extjs column

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $string = 'Faz 1/İzmir/İzmir/Konak';

    $array = array();
    for($a='a'; $a!='y'; $a++){
        $array[] = strtolower($a);
        $array[] = strtoupper($a);
    }
    $array[] = 'z';
    $array[] = 'Z';

    $str = '';
    for($x=0; $x<=strlen($string)-1; $x++){
        if(!in_array($string[$x],$array)){
            $str .= $string[$x];
        }
    }
    var_dump($str);
?>
```